# Bluetooth Arduino Data Type Error

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

In my code I want to send some float values from my phone to the Arduino's Bluetooth which I will then split using the substring function. it will then print that split value to the serial monitor.

I don't even know what is wrong but there is no error and it just spits out the ascii code of those numbers (not split). Please help if anyone has any idea.
Here is my code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
#define TxD 3 
#define RxD 2 
SoftwareSerial bluetoothSerial(TxD,RxD);

String Sstring;
String arrayOne;

void setup() 
{
  bluetoothSerial.begin(9600);  
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
 
 if(bluetoothSerial.available()>0)
 {
  
  arrayOne=bluetoothSerial.read();
  
  Sstring=arrayOne.substring(0);
  Serial.println(Sstring);
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you have to decide what data format the phone application
will use for sending the data to the Arduino: define a “language” of
sorts. Then you have to program both the phone and the Arduino to speak
that same language.

Unless the data throughput is critical, I strongly advise you to use a
text-based format, where each “message” is followed by a dedicated
character that signals the end of the message. Popular choices for the
message terminator are `'\n'` (ASCII line feed, numeric value 0x0a =
10), `'\r'` (carriage return = 0x0d = 13) and `';'` (semicolon = 0x3b =
59). The semicolon is often used as a second-level separator, to split a
message into smaller fields.

Here is a simple example that reads one-line messages, using a line feed
as a delimiter:

```cpp
void loop() {
    if (bluetoothSerial.available() > 0) {
        String message = bluetoothSerial.readStringUntil('\n');
        Serial.println(message);
    }
}
```

If you want to send the data as binary, then message framing becomes a
tricky problem. Since every possible byte value can legitimately appear
within the message (any byte can appear within a float), you cannot
simply reserve one byte to serve as a terminator. This is why, unless
you are an advanced programmer, I strongly encourage you to send
whatever data you want to send as text. Text also makes debugging much
easier.

Finally, I have to warn you that the `String` class is not friendly to
the memory of your Arduino, and can lead to instabilities if used
extensively. If you have time, I encourage you to study the robust way
to read text from the serial port: see the article [Reading Serial on
the Arduino](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/our-blog-1/reading-serial-on-the-arduino-27), by Majenko.

Comment: Hey , Thanks for your reply . I tried out your code and it seemed to show no errors (which is good) but when I tried to send a message from my phone and then used the \n terminator , the IDE didn't care , it just printed the whole message . I saw some logs regarding substring and readstringuntil but found no answer . I probably think its still the data type error .Thanks still !

Comment: @CodeStuff: What do you mean by “_the IDE didn't care_”? The IDE has nothing to do with this. If the Arduino did not find the line feed terminator, that's because you did not send it from the phone. Did you send the two characters `'\'` and `'n'` instead? I do not know what programming environment you are using on the phone side, or whether you really know how to properly use it, but it is essential that _you know what you are sending_. If line feed is too complicated for that environment, try `';'`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the line `arrayOne=bluetoothSerial.read();`
is converting the received value to a string (character array of ASCII charachters terminated with the '\0' character).
Then, you copy that string to another string variable. If you want to split the string you should:

- define a starting character > 0
- and/or: define an ending character < the total string size.

See [this link](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/substring/) for more info.

You could try the following. I'm sure it's far from perfect but it might get you a bit further.

```
void setup()
{
    bluetoothSerial.begin(9600);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    if (bluetoothSerial.available)
    {
        delay(100); // wait a little for the serial buffer to saturate. This value should be as short as possible

        // Save the buffer bytes as the float (Big Endian!)
        double received_float = (bluetoothSerial.read() << 24) | (bluetoothSerial.read() << 16) | (bluetoothSerial.read() << 8) | (bluetoothSerial.read());
        Serial.println(received_float);
    }
}
```

Some conciderations:

- The nr of bytes a float occupies may differ on your phone and your Arduino. The example above uses a 32-bit float
- If possible you'd want to start the transmission with a sequency of starting characters. That way, you can be sure to read the proper value.

Comment: There are multiple issues with this way of building the float from individual bytes: 1. The order of the bytes is not defined: it will be whatever order this version of the compiler decides this day to use. 2. Shifting by 16 or 24 bits will overflow on an Uno. 3. This cannot work for a float: you will get the bits of the original float interpreted as an integer, and that integer represented as a (very different) float.

Comment: Hey , I tried using the code , but  there was no message printed itself .